# Pandas Advanced: How to get results for customer who has bought at least twice within 5 days of period?

Tags: python, pandas

I have been attempting to solve a problem for hours and stuck on it. Here is the problem outline:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'orderid': [10315, 10318, 10321, 10473, 10621, 10253, 10541, 10645],
          'customerid': ['ISLAT', 'ISLAT', 'ISLAT', 'ISLAT', 'ISLAT', 'HANAR', 'HANAR', 'HANAR'],
          'orderdate': ['1996-09-26', '1996-10-01', '1996-10-03', '1997-03-13', '1997-08-05', '1996-07-10', '1997-05-19', '1997-08-26']})
df

   orderid customerid   orderdate
0    10315      ISLAT  1996-09-26
1    10318      ISLAT  1996-10-01
2    10321      ISLAT  1996-10-03
3    10473      ISLAT  1997-03-13
4    10621      ISLAT  1997-08-05
5    10253      HANAR  1996-07-10
6    10541      HANAR  1997-05-19
7    10645      HANAR  1997-08-26
```

I would like to select all the customers who has ordered items more than once WITHIN 5 DAYS.

For example, here only the customer ordered within 5 days of period and he has done it twice.

I would like to get the output in the following format:

## Required Output

```
customerid  initial_order_id    initial_order_date  nextorderid nextorderdate   daysbetween
ISLAT       10315               1996-09-26          10318       1996-10-01      5
ISLAT       10318               1996-10-01          10321       1996-10-03      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create the column 'daysbetween' with `sort_values` and `diff`. After to get the following order, you can `join` df with df once `groupby` per customerid and `shift` all the data. Finally, `query` where the number of days in 'daysbetween_next ' is met:

```
df['daysbetween'] = df.sort_values(['customerid', 'orderdate'])['orderdate'].diff().dt.days
df_final = df.join(df.groupby('customerid').shift(-1), 
                   lsuffix='_initial', rsuffix='_next')\
             .drop('daysbetween_initial', axis=1)\
             .query('daysbetween_next <= 5 and daysbetween_next >=0')
```

Answer (score 2):

First, to be able to count the difference in days, convert *orderdate*
column to *datetime*:

```
df.orderdate = pd.to_datetime(df.orderdate)
```

Then define the following function:

```
def fn(grp):
    return grp[(grp.orderdate.shift(-1) - grp.orderdate) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D') <= 5]
```

And finally apply it:

```
df.sort_values(['customerid', 'orderdate']).groupby('customerid').apply(fn)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit tricky because there can be any number of purchase pairs within 5 day windows. It is a good use case for leveraging `merge_asof`, which allows to do approximate-but-not-exact matching of a dataframe with itself.

Input data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'orderid': [10315, 10318, 10321, 10473, 10621, 10253, 10541, 10645],
          'customerid': ['ISLAT', 'ISLAT', 'ISLAT', 'ISLAT', 'ISLAT', 'HANAR', 'HANAR', 'HANAR'],
          'orderdate': ['1996-09-26', '1996-10-01', '1996-10-03', '1997-03-13', '1997-08-05', '1996-07-10', '1997-05-19', '1997-08-26']})
```

Define a function that computes the pairs of purchases, given data for a customer.

```
def compute_purchase_pairs(df):
    # Approximate self join on the date, but not exact.
    df_combined = pd.merge_asof(df,df, left_index=True, right_index=True,
                                suffixes=('_first', '_second') , allow_exact_matches=False)
    # Compute difference
    df_combined['timedelta'] = df_combined['orderdate_first'] - df_combined['orderdate_second']
    return df_combined
```

Do the preprocessing and compute the pairs

```
# Convert to datetime
df['orderdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['orderdate'])
# Sort dataframe from last buy to newest (groupby will not change this order)
df2 = df.sort_values(by='orderdate', ascending=False)
# Create an index for joining
df2 = df.set_index('orderdate', drop=False)

# Compute puchases pairs for each customer
df_differences = df2.groupby('customerid').apply(compute_purchase_pairs)
# Show only the ones we care about
result = df_differences[df_differences['timedelta'].dt.days<=5]
result.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result

```
   orderid_first customerid_first orderdate_first  orderid_second  \
0          10318            ISLAT      1996-10-01         10315.0   
1          10321            ISLAT      1996-10-03         10318.0   

  customerid_second orderdate_second timedelta  
0             ISLAT       1996-09-26    5 days  
1             ISLAT       1996-10-01    2 days
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple. Let's write down the requirements one at the time and try to build upon.

First, I guess that the customer has a unique id since it's not specified. We'll use that id for identifying customers.

Second, I assume it does not matter if the customer bought 5 days before or after.

My solution, is to use a simple filter. Note that this solution can also be implemented in a SQL database.

As a condition, we require the user to be the same. We can achieve this as follows:

```
new_df = df[df["ID"] == df["ID"].shift(1)]
```

We create a new DataFrame, namely new_df, with all rows such that the xth row has the same user id as the xth - 1 row (i.e. the previous row).

Now, let's search for purchases within the 5 days, by adding the condition to the previous piece of code

```
new_df = df[df["ID"] == df["ID"].shift(1) & (df["Date"] - df["Date"].shift(1)) <= 5]
```

This should do the work. I cannot test it write now, so some fixes may be needed. I'll try to test it as soon as I can